# How to add calculated row based on mulitple column and row values in r in?

Tags: r, dplyr, calculated-columns

If I have a dataframe below and I want to add another row for each group in r:

dataframe before:

```
Letter   Value
A         1
A         2
A         3
B         1
B         2
B         3
```

If I just wanted to add another row for each group that averaged those rows, how would I go about that:

dataframe after:

```
Letter   Value
A         1
A         2
A         3
A         2
B         1
B         2
B         3
B         2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution could be

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Letter),
    function(x) rbind(x, c(unique(x$Letter), mean(x$Value)))))
#    Letter Value
#A.1       A     1
#A.2       A     2
#A.3       A     3
#A.4       A     2
#B.4       B     1
#B.5       B     2
#B.6       B     3
#B.41      B     2
```

This requires column `Letter` to be a `character` vector. If `Letter` is a `factor` you can convert from `factor` to `character` vector

```
df$Letter <- as.character(df$Letter)
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Letter   Value
A         1
A         2
A         3
B         1
B         2
B         3", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the mean of value by letter giving `ag`, rbind that to the end of `DF` giving `DF2` and sort.

```
ag <- aggregate(value ~ letter, DF, mean)
DF2 <- rbind(DF, ag)

o <- order(DF2$letter, rownames(DF2))
DF2[o, ]
```

giving:

```
  letter value
1      A     1
2      A     2
3      A     3
7      A     2
4      B     1
5      B     2
6      B     3
8      B     2
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- data.frame(letter = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3), value = 1:3)
```